# How do I get touch coordinates with respect to canvas after scaling and translating?

Tags: android, canvas

I need to get the touch x and y with respect to the canvas to check for collisions and things like that after I have moved and scaled the canvas.

I already managed to get the touch coordinate whenever I translate the canvas or scale it around the origin (0,0) by using the following code:

```
private float convertToCanvasCoordinate(float touchx, float touchy) {
    float newX=touchx/scale-translatex;
    float newY=touchy/scale-translatey
}
```

But if I scale the canvas around another point like for example `canvas.scale(scale,scale,50,50)`, it doesn't work .

I know it shouldn't work but I just couldn't figure out how to solve it. I already looked at other questions but none of the answers talks about how to get the coordinate if I scale according to a specific point.

Comment: You can find what you are looking for in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34598847/3877726 It is in javascript but the math is identical. To find a point in a transformed view invert transformation matrix and multiply the touch coords with the inv matrix. It will handle all situations including skew and shear.

Comment: the code didn't work :( ,it doesn't seem to handle  scaling at specific point

Comment: This already has an answere here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061734/how-do-i-make-the-coordinates-of-motionevent-match-the-ones-of-a-scaled-canvas

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The most basic way to properly do a scene in android is to use a matrix to modify the view and the inverse of that matrix to modify your touches. Here's a simplified answer. Kept very short.

```
public class SceneView extends View {
    Matrix viewMatrix = new Matrix(), invertMatrix = new Matrix();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ArrayList<RectF> rectangles = new ArrayList<>();
    RectF moving = null;

    public SceneView(Context context) { super(context); }
    public SceneView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { super(context, attrs); }
    public SceneView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) { super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr); }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //transform touch. (inverted matrix)
        event.transform(invertMatrix);
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                moving = null;
                //collision detection
                for (RectF f : rectangles) {
                    if (f.contains(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                        moving = f;
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                // adding arbitrary transforms.
                viewMatrix.postTranslate(50,50);
                viewMatrix.postScale(.99f,.99f);
                viewMatrix.postRotate(5);
                // inverse matrix is needed for touches.
                invertMatrix = new Matrix(viewMatrix);
                invertMatrix.invert(invertMatrix);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (moving != null) {
                    moving.set(event.getX() - 50, event.getY() - 50, event.getX() + 50, event.getY() + 50);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (moving == null) {
                    rectangles.add(new RectF(event.getX() - 50, event.getY() - 50, event.getX() + 50, event.getY() + 50));
                }
                break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // transform the view by the matrix.
        canvas.concat(viewMatrix);
        // draw objects
        for (RectF f : rectangles) {
            canvas.drawRect(f,paint);
        }
    }
```

This is rather minimalist, but it shows all the relevant aspects.

1. Moving the view
2. Touch modification
3. Collision detection.

Each time you touch the screen it will move diagonally, zoomout, and rotate (basically moves in a spiral), and create a black rectangle. If you touch the rectangles you can move them around to your heart's content. When you click the background, more spiraling the view, dropping black rectangles.

See: https://youtu.be/-XSjanaAdWA

---

The other way does not work. You could, in theory, take the scene we want and convert that via the View class rather than in the canvas. This would make the touch events occur in the same space as the screen. But Android will void out touch events that occur outside of the view, So MotionEvents that begin outside of the original clipped part of the view will be discarded. So this is a non-starter. You want to transform the canvas, and counter transform the MotionEvents.

Comment: thx you very much for your quick response ,i really appreciate it but your code is really big :) ,i just found out that there is a function canvas.getclipbound which gets me the visible viewport of the screen along with the offset x and y which solved my problem ,check my answer for more details

Comment: It's the top part that really matters, you can basically narrow it down ti simply two matricies. and using them on the onDraw and onTouch events.

Comment: Should be, it's a modified version of the same concepts I use for "Touch Embroidery Free" I wrote and put on google Play. But more than the working code bit, is the importance of the concepts. Basically that you can apply the matrix to the canvas you draw on, then apply the inverse of that matrix on the touch events. With just those two relevant lines of code, (and something setting up the matrix) *all* work is done for you. You could literally skew the view, or animate the entire view rotating around some point, at some speed, and have the touch events line up perfectly with the scene.

Comment: Okay, shrank the code down to the essential bits (then added some really basic non-essential bits).

Comment: And generally speaking, it's the correct way to look at them. Once you understand that the math to convert the scene drawing to the view and touches to the view, is just a matrix object. Basically you can do anything there with very little effort. It simplifies everything greatly. I myself even wrote an entire Widget Scene system much like Visual Library API for Netbeans and most other systems. So, you get a basically infinite field to work with, and can properly manipulate any number of widgets while only needing a few lines of code for a world of functionality.

Comment: This should be upvoted more, you just saved me a ton of confusion. I was transforming by the same matrix as I used for the canvas, didn't even think I needed the INVERSE! Life saver! Didn't realise MotionEvent had a Transform method either, very handy, no more MapPoints for me!

Answer (score 4):

```
 private float convertToCanvasXCoordinate(float touchx,float offsetx,float viewportVisibleWidth){
        float newx=(touchx*viewportVisibleWidth)/getWidth()+offsetx;
        return newx;
    }

    private float convertToCanvasYCoordinate(float touchy,float offsety,float viewportVisibleHeight){
        float newy=(touchy*viewportVisibleHeight)/getHeight()+offsety;
        return newy;
    }
```

i just found out there is a function canvas.getClipBound() which is a rectangle representing the visible viewport that includes the offsetx offset y (the left and top of the rectangle respectively) and the viewport width and height

simply call these functions and it will get you  touchx and touchy with respect to canvas

Comment: for the life of me I cloud not have figured this out until I saw your post. thanks mate

Comment: @has19 what is getWidth() and getHeight() here, from where do they come from?

Comment: @zeeali I think they are the view width and height so in this case they would be the canvas size.

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
float px = e.getX() / mScaleFactorX;
float py = e.getY() / mScaleFactorY;
int ipy = (int) py;
int ipx = (int) px;
Rect r = new Rect(ipx, ipy, ipx+2, ipy+2);
```

And where the canvas is:

```
    final float scaleFactorX = getWidth()/(WIDTH*1.f);
    final float scaleFactorY = getHeight()/(HEIGHT*1.f);

    if(mScaleFactorX == INVALID){
        mScaleFactorX = scaleFactorX;
        mScaleFactorY = scaleFactorY;
    }
```

This is a really simple way, and it works because it scales down the onTouch coordinates to be the same min/max as the canvas, causing them to be scaled. Do NOT use getRawX and getRawY because that will return wrong coordinates if you are using a custom layout with the view added and other elements around it. getX and getY returns the accurate coordinates scaled to your view.

This is really simple and does not take up a lot of code. scaleFactor can be used elsewhere to handle zoom(you take care of that code) but what this code does is to handle the issue of getting the pointer coordinates to match the scaled canvas